# Unexpected operations inside the classes of Migration folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, migration

After writing the initial model, I added the migration by using command Add-Migration from the console. The three migration files were created but I had some unexpected and undefined operations in the files.

Student Class:

```
public class Student

{
    public string StudentsUserId { get; set; }
    public bool is_accepted { get; set; }
    public int Number_preferences { get; set; }

    public List<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
    public List<Offers> Offers { get; set; }
    public List List { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IList<Courscategory> courshistory { get; set; }

}
```

}

OffersClass:

```
   public class Offers
    {
        public string CourseID { get; set; }

        public string SupervisorUserId { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Max_student { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CourseDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public int CourseAvaialbility { get; set; }
        public string Requirements { get; set; }
        public bool IsFull { get; set; }


        public Supervisors Supervisor { get; set; }  //Supervisor is a separate class
        public List<CList> List { get; set; }

    }
}
```

List Class:

```
   public class List
    {
        public string CourseID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string StudentsUserId { get; set; }
        public string SupervisorUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public Offers Offer { get; set; }
        public List<Students> Studnets { get; set; }
        public List<Supervisors> Supervisor { get; set; }

        public List<Preference> Preference { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Code in Migration File:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CStudents",
            columns: table => new
            {
                StudentsUserId= table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                is_accepted = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                Number_preferences = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ListCourseID = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CStudents", x => x.StudentsUserId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_StudentsUserId_List_ListCourseID",
                    column: x => x.ListCourseID,
                    principalTable: "List",
                    principalColumn: "CourseID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Initial model code:

```
public class CFE_CrazyLabContext : DbContext
{
    public CFE_CrazyLabContext(DbContextOptions<CFE_CrazyLabContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<LearnAngebot.Models.CStudents> Students{ get; set; }      

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<CStudents>().HasKey(o => o.StudentsUserId);

    }
}
```

The ListCourseId does not exist in the Student class not is it a variable of that class. No idea how these operations got added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your Class offers has a reference for Students but your class students does not have a reference for Offers. If you add one it should be fine

Answer (score 2):

After the edit, It looks like you mixed up the relations a bit, per your comment you stated that the Foreign Key that Entity Framework created for you is wrong, this would be because you swapped it around. The FKey you added to the List class in StudentsUserId currently is just a extra field that doesn't do much special.

In the class student the link to the list class should look like this

```
public class Student

{
    public string StudentsUserId { get; set; }
    public bool is_accepted { get; set; }
    public int Number_preferences { get; set; }

    public List<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
    public List<Offers> Offers { get; set; }

    public List<List> List { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IList<Courscategory> courshistory { get; set; }

}
```

and in your List class it should look like this:

```
public class List
    {
        public string CourseID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string StudentsUserId { get; set; }
        public string SupervisorUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public Offers Offer { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }

        public List<Supervisors> Supervisor { get; set; }
        public List<Preference> Preference { get; set; }
    }
```

The generated extra field "ListCourseId" feels like just an automatically generated field by EF following the pattern [Table]+[PKey].

Comment: Yes the list class has a foreign key StudentsUserId through which it connects to the Student class but the Student class does not have any foreign key (only a primary key- StudentsUserId). Besides, ListCourseId does not exist anywhere in the code. There is just a class List which has the variable CourseId. So I feel something strange has been generated.

Comment: @user11692177 Updated answer as per your comment and updated question